# What type of device should I get to be a wireless repeater and a wired hub?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

This is a home networking question. I have a lan (cat-5) connection into a room that has poor wireless connectivity.  I have few devices around the connection point and running a wired connection to them would be great.  But I would like to also repeat the wireless signal at that point also.  My primary wireless routed in my basement feeds most of my house just fine but this particular room.

What type of device should I get?  Ideally I would 3-4 wired connections I could use for my docking station or two.

Comment: [Netgear EX-7000](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-range-extenders/EX7000.aspx) in access point mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up a Wireless Repeater in a home network](http://superuser.com/questions/373414/setting-up-a-wireless-repeater-in-a-home-network)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider adding a second, wireless router to that room, but configuring it as a client bridge instead of a traditional router. If said router doesn't have any preconfigured profile for that use case, normally disabling any DHCP server running on it and any settings used to filter traffic will do the trick.

With the right router, you can knock out two birds with one stone:

- A second wireless access point configured similarly to your primary router would allow your devices already configured to work seamlessly with a much better signal.
- The Ethernet ports on your router essentially functions as a switch. You could connect your wired devices through this to your network. One possible caveat: if said router does not allow for repurposing your uplink port, you would have to sacrifice one port as an uplink to the rest of your network. However, you could always daisy chain additional switches to get around this.

[Here's an article](http://www.howtogeek.com/104469/how-to-extend-your-wi-fi-network-with-simple-access-points/) which may help you to get a better idea of what needs to be done.